# Could not load file or assembly '...' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, 64-bit, iis-7.5, web-deployment

**NOTE: I know this has been posted before but i have tried the solutions presented in other threads and haven't had any luck yet**

I'm trying to deploy a NET 4.0 MVC 4 Application onto an IIS server (version 7.5). I get the following error:

[image]

The server is running Windows 7 64 bits. I'm using two "special" libraries:

-EPPlus

-itextsharp

Notes:

-The application pool has the following config:

[image]

Help please :(

Comment: Do what it says : Put the fusion log on and see what failed in the log. http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsUsingFusionLogViewerToDebugObscureLoaderErrors.aspx

Comment: Enable 32-bit applicaions and try?

Comment: I have tried that already, changed it to try something else and forgot to turn it back on.

Answer (score 4):

Probably, you are trying to load x32 DLL. Try to change "Enable 32-bit Applications" to "true".

Comment: Sorry, the screenshot was outdated. I've tried both values (true and false). no luck

Comment: @J_Ocampo, So what platform target has been set at project properties for UPC.SCEP.PL.UI?

Answer (score 1):

On your project, right-click, and in the properties menu, change the platform target to any CPU.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a couple of time a similar error, failing to load some file or their dependencies.

What worked out for me, despite doing what [Den](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20158367/1501497) said, is if available then uninstall the x64 application and download and install the x86 (the 32 bits version) of the same application.

Or if you are developing it, make sure you do as [jos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70504457/1501497) said, and change the target of your application to 32-bits.

that worked for me on different occasions. The error messages don't give you a direct instruction really.

[image]