# Could not load file or assembly 'EasyXLS, Version=8.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=632c31013494909a' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, .net-4.5

We have project in .Net 4.5 Framework.Recently I used Third party dll EasyXls (64 bit).My machine is also based on 64 bit .I am getting run time error as per below .

> "Could not load file or assembly 'EasyXLS, Version=8.4.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=632c31013494909a' or one of its
>   dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect
>   format."

Note: When I am building solution using .net 4 than I am not getting any runtime error.In My project properties I have setup platform target as "Any CPU"

*Can you please give me some direction to resolve this problem ?*

**Stack Trace :**

> Could not load file or assembly 'EasyXLS' or one of its dependencies.
>   An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file
>   or assembly 'EasyXLS' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made
>   to load a program with an incorrect format.

**Source Error:**

> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to
>   determine why the assembly 'EasyXLS' could not be loaded.

=== Pre-bind state information ===

> LOG: DisplayName = EasyXLS  (Partial) WRN: Partial binding information
>   was supplied for an assembly: WRN: Assembly Name: EasyXLS | Domain ID:
>   2 WRN: A partial bind occurs when only part of the assembly display
>   name is provided. WRN: This might result in the binder loading an
>   incorrect assembly. WRN: It is recommended to provide a fully
>   specified textual identity for the assembly, WRN: that consists of the
>   simple name, version, culture, and public key token. WRN: See
>   whitepaper http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more
>   information and common solutions to this issue. LOG: Appbase =
>   file:///C:/MarketPlace/Market Place/Source
>   Code/Trasix.MarketPlace/MP.Services/ LOG: Initial PrivatePath =
>   C:\MarketPlace\Market Place\Source
>   Code\Trasix.MarketPlace\MP.Services\bin Calling assembly : (Unknown).
>   === LOG: This bind starts in default load context. LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\MarketPlace\Market Place\Source
>   Code\Trasix.MarketPlace\MP.Services\web.config LOG: Using host
>   configuration file:
>   C:\Users\Rakesh\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config LOG: Using
>   machine configuration file from
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
>   LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private,
>   custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind). LOG: Attempting
>   download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Users/Rakesh/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files/vs/012c8e97/a400721c/EasyXLS.DLL. LOG: Attempting download of
>   new URL file:///C:/Users/Rakesh/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files/vs/012c8e97/a400721c/EasyXLS/EasyXLS.DLL. LOG: Attempting
>   download of new URL file:///C:/MarketPlace/Market Place/Source
>   Code/Trasix.MarketPlace/MP.Services/bin/EasyXLS.DLL. ERR: Failed to
>   complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x8007000b). Probing terminated.

**Stack Trace:**

> [BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'EasyXLS' or
>   one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an
>   incorrect format.]
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String
>   codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks) +0
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String
>   codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks) +34
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName
>   assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks) +152
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr
>   pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +77
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean
>   forIntrospection) +16    System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String
>   assemblyString) +28
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String
>   assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +38
>
> [ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'EasyXLS' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a
>   program with an incorrect format.]
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String
>   assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +736
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory()
>   +217    System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo
>   ai) +130
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection
>   compConfig) +170
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies()
>   +91    System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String
>   preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +284
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +153
>   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager
>   appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory
>   configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters,
>   PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +521
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'EasyXLS'
>   or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with
>   an incorrect format.]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9930568 
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
>   +101    System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +254
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34212

**=== Web.config ===**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>


  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="ExcelHeaderStartIndex" value="1"/>
    <add key="ExcelRowDataIndex" value="2"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
    <profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <!--
            If you are deploying to a cloud environment that has multiple web server instances,
            you should change session state mode from "InProc" to "Custom". In addition,
            change the connection string named "DefaultConnection" to connect to an instance
            of SQL Server (including SQL Azure and SQL  Compact) instead of to SQL Server Express.
      -->
    <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />

  <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers></system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.3.0.0" newVersion="1.3.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.3.0.0" newVersion="1.3.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.2.0" newVersion="5.2.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.2.0" newVersion="5.2.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: in dll reference properties. what is the value for 'copy local' ?

Comment: 'copy local' is True

Comment: If your third party library is based on .NET 4.5 you won't be able to load it in a .NET 4 Project since it will lack 4.5 references.

Comment: third party library  is supporting all version of .Net framework from 2.0 to 4.5

Comment: Yes i saw that but did you load a copy of the dll file you were using with the 4.5 build or did you add the refenrence from the GAC after having changed the targeted Framework

Comment: I have added dll file with 4.5 build.My all project libraries developed using framework 4.5. I just added easy xls dll in those project libraries and got runtime exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you are loading a x32 dll library on a x64 application. Try to change "Enable 32-bit Applications" to "true".

[Could not load file or assembly '...' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20158318/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-or-one-of-its-dependencies-an-attempt-was)

Also check the platform target:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/383138/BadImageFormatException-x-i-x

**Your problem it's that you are debugging with IIS Express (32 bits) and you can not use that DLL on IIS Express (debugging). Change your DLL to 32 bits or change on Project Properties - >Servers ->Local IIS (if your machine it's 64 bits of course)**

[image]

Comment: Hello Phx, I have added 64 bit dll library on x64 application. so i dont think so i need to change "Enable 32-bit Applications" to "true".

Comment: Anyway, try it. If the error still happening lets try another solution.

Comment: Can you post the webconfig in order to check how the assemby is registered?

Comment: Phx: I have added my web.config in Posted question section

Comment: Can't see the EasyXLS reference. How did you add the reference to the project?

Comment: I have added reference using "Add reference" option in Project

Comment: Your problem it's that you are debugging with IIS Express (32 bits) and you can not use that DLL on IIS Express (debugging). Change your DLL to 32 bits or change on Project Properties - >Servers ->Local IIS (if your machine it's 64 bits of course)